# MongoDB aggregation sum untill with condition (if/else) OR count price and quantity problem

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

> THE PROBLEM

I'm writing a function that could calculated `avg price` and entire `value` based on requested `quantity`, for example:

```
async funcName (first_100) {
        let market_quantity = await auctions_db.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    item: 9999,
                }
            },
            {
                $sort: {
                    price: 1
                }
            },
            //RESULT
        ]);
}
```

> //RESULT

At this point I have following docs:

```
{
    item_id: 9999,
    price: 1..Number
    quantity: 1..200
    value: price x quantity //it's not virtual field
},{
    another doc...
}
```

As I mentioned above the thing that I want it to, is to `$sum` `price` field until `quantity` won't hit 100 or 100+ (or any other number depends on function argument).

*I don't need to `$sum` first 100 docs (which are sorted by `price` ascending, I would use `.limit` in that case)*

So it's obvious I have two ways to do so. As for now I'm using `collection.find({condition}).cursor()` with the same condition and iterate doc over doc in separate `for loop`, but I know (actually a friend told me) that *MongoDB* could do the same via `aggregate` stage via `$cond` (if/else) block.

Actually I guess that the next `$operator` after `//Result` in that case should be `$group` stage, like this:

```
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$lastModified",
                    quantity: {$sum: {$cond: if/else }" $quantity"},
                    if (below 100) {$sum: "$value" }
                }
            }
```

But I have no idea how to do it. So can anyone provide me an example of that? 
Or there is no difference between `aggregate` stage and `.find({}).cursor` and manual iteration?

Comment: I will suggest go with aggregation queries where first you filter based on your if/else condition and then apply the accumulator

Comment: so I should use `$filter` firstly after `$match` and `$sort` and then if/else `$condition` block?

Comment: other thing you can do is apply a reduce function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/index.html

Comment: @Ricardo according to mongodb docs `map-reduce` looks like a perfect solution, if I understand it correctly of course. As for now, I'll dig it that way.

Comment: $filter will be the if/else condition and then apply $sum, if you need to do this for docs that does not enter in the if condition you can use $facet to group based on condition

Comment: be careful with the memory while using mapreduce, queries and agregrations are always be faster

Comment: @Ricardo oh, I already know that (so I bought a few more GBs of `RAM`) actually one more question about that. `Indexes` in the collection could heavily increase performance of `queries` and `aggregate` operations. Are they still effective for `map-reduce` ?

Comment: map-reduce is going to be running in memory after getting the collection I don't think will increase performance if you put indexes in the collection, go for aggregation, you will thank me later ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solve my problem via `find({query}).cursor()` syntax and pushing to array(s) like:

```
        let market_quantity = await auctions_db.find({query}).cursor();
        for (let order = await market_quantity.next(); order != null; order = await market_quantity.next()) {
            if (quantity < arg_quantity) {
                quantity += order.quantity;
                price_array.push(order.price);
                value += order.buyout;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```